# Session not working on server, but works on localhost

Tags: php, mysql, session, authentication

I keep getting redirected to the login page after i have logged in, but no such error when I run the script on the `localhost`.
This is the login script:

**login.php**

```
<?php
//...
if(array_key_exists('submit',$_POST))
{
$username = $db->sanitizeData($_POST['username']);
$password = $db->sanitizeData($_POST['password']);

$db->executeQuery("SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE username = '$username' AND password = SHA1('$password')");
$count = $db->numRows();

if ($count == 0)
    header("location: ../index.php?error=1");

else
{
    $row =  $db->fetch_object();
    $user_id = $row->admin_id;
    $admin_status = $row->status;

    $session = new session();
    $session->setSession("s_user_id", $user_id);
    $session->setSession("admin_status", $admin_status);

    $db->executeQuery("SELECT session_id FROM another_table WHERE status=1");
    $row = $db->fetch_object();
    $session_id = $row->session_id;
    $session->setSession("session_id", $session_id);
    header("location: ../home.php");
    }
}

?>
```

On the 
**home.php**
I included a file that has the following codes:

```
<?php
//...
$session = new session();
$user_id = $session->retrieveSession('s_user_id');

if (!isset($user_id)) 
header("location: ../administrator/index.php");
//...
?>
```

On the `localhost`, I am not getting any issue, but if I am trying to run the page on a live server, it redirects back to the `login.php`, instead of `home.php`
Thank you, everyone.

Comment: Is there a session inserted into the database on login on the server?

Comment: Perhaps the databases are different?

Comment: @Greg Nope, I guess thats the issue, I cant seem to find out why

Comment: @PolarB. did you set up the database exactly as you had it on your first server? Does the user have the correct permissions?

Comment: Yea, i actually exported the database from Localhost to server. @Greg